# Finding multiple “most common values” in a column

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, worksheet-function

I am trying to display the 5 most commonly appearing text values in a column in Google Sheets.

The following will give me the most common value in column A:

```
=ArrayFormula(INDEX(A:A,MODE(MATCH(A:A,A:A,0))))
```

And this will give me the second most common value in column A, assuming that the formula above is in cell G2 (whose result is being excluded):

```
=ArrayFormula(INDEX(A:A,MODE(IF(A:A<>G2,MATCH(A:A,A:A,0)))))
```

How can I get the third, fourth, fifth, etc most common values? Something like this does not work:

```
=ArrayFormula(INDEX(A:A,MODE(IF(A:A<>G2:G3,MATCH(A:A,A:A,0)))))
```

Basically, I need to exclude multiple values from that calculation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=QUERY(QUERY(B:B,
 "select B,count(B) 
  where B is not null 
  group by B 
  order by count(B) desc 
  label count(B)''", 0), 
 "select Col1
  limit 5", 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Is there a simple way to extend this to multiple most common values in a block such as A:C?

Comment: @wilsnunn sure: `=QUERY(QUERY(FLATTEN(A:C),
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  order by count(Col1) desc 
  label count(Col1)''", 0), 
 "select Col1
  limit 5", 0)`